# Android Plot: how to refresh in real time a chart

Tags: android, charts

I'm designing an android application where I want to plot real time data which I receive through blue-tooth in a linear chart.
I tried to use float-android-chart, acharengine and android plot, but i can't print a chart and next print the same chart with different x axis values(seconds) and different series of values.
I tried all the things that I found on Internet, but not work.
Can you show me a very simple code that repaint a chart, or I modify one of this 2 code in order to repaint the char?

with android plot:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private XYPlot plot;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xy_plot_chart);
        chart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    plot.clear();
    chart();
    plot.redraw();
}

private void chart() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.xyPlot);

    List s1 = getSeries(20, 10);
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(s1,
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series 1");

    List s2 = getSeries(20, 10);
    XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(s2,
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series 2");

    LineAndPointFormatter s1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
    s1Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
    s1Format.configure(getApplicationContext(),
            R.xml.lpf1);
    plot.addSeries(series1, s1Format);

    LineAndPointFormatter s2Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
    s2Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
    s2Format.configure(getApplicationContext(),
            R.xml.lpf2);
    plot.addSeries(series2, s2Format);

    plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(1);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(-45);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private List getSeries(int count, int max) {
    List series = new ArrayList();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        int value = rand.nextInt(max);
        series.add(rand.nextInt(max));
    }
    return series;
}
}
```

or with achartengine:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//int n =0;
int count = 5;
Date[] dt = new Date[5];
int [] prova = { 0,1,2,3,4 }; 

long timerStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
int timeout = 0;
long[] timerNow = {0,0,0,0,0};
int[] visits = { 2000,2500,2700,2100,2800};
int[] views = {2200, 2700, 2900, 2800, 3200}; 
private GraphicalView mChart;   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    openChart();      
}

private void openChart(){       

    //while(n<5){
    /*
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, i+1);
        dt[i] = gc.getTime();
    }*/
    for(int i=0 ;i<count;i++){
    timerNow[i] = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    // Creating TimeSeries for Visits
    TimeSeries timeSeriesVisits = new TimeSeries("Visits");     
    // Creating TimeSeries for Views
    TimeSeries timeSeriesViews= new TimeSeries("Views");        

    timeSeriesVisits = new TimeSeries("Visits"); 
    timeSeriesViews = new TimeSeries("Views"); 

    // Adding data to Visits and Views Series
    for(int i=0;i<dt.length;i++){
        timeSeriesVisits.add(timerNow[i], visits[i]);
        timeSeriesViews.add(timerNow[i],views[i]);
    }

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(timeSeriesVisits);

    // Adding Visits Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(timeSeriesViews);     


    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries      
    XYSeriesRenderer visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize viewsSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer viewsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    viewsRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    viewsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    viewsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    viewsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    viewsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Visits vs Views Chart");
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Tempo");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Count");
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);      

    // Adding visitsRenderer and viewsRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(viewsRenderer);

    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

    // Creating a Time Chart
    //mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer,"dd-MMM-yyyy");           
    //mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer);
    //mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, );
    //mChart= ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, "HH-MM-SS");
    mChart = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, "Consumption");
    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    //Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
    //chartContainer.addView(mChart);
    //dataset.addSeries(timeSeriesVisits);
    //dataset.addSeries(timeSeriesViews);
    //mChart = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, "Consumption");

    mChart.refreshDrawableState();
    //mChart.repaint();
    setContentView(mChart);

    //n++;
    //}

    // Setting a click event listener for the graph
    mChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

            if (seriesSelection != null) {                  
                int seriesIndex = seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex();
                String selectedSeries="Visits";
                if(seriesIndex==0)
                    selectedSeries = "Visits";
                else
                    selectedSeries = "Views";

                // Getting the clicked Date ( x value )
                long clickedDateSeconds = (long) seriesSelection.getXValue();
                Date clickedDate = new Date(clickedDateSeconds);
                String strDate = formatter.format(clickedDate);

                // Getting the y value 
                int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();

                // Displaying Toast Message
                Toast.makeText(
                       getBaseContext(),
                       selectedSeries + " on "  + strDate + " : " + amount ,
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK DONE:

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-dynamic-chart-using-achartengine/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {      
private GraphicalView mChart;       
private XYSeries visitsSeries ;     
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;      
private XYSeriesRenderer visitsRenderer;     
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer;       

@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);           
    // Setting up chart        
    setupChart();           
    // Start plotting chart       
    new ChartTask().execute();       
}       

private void setupChart(){           
    // Creating an  XYSeries for Visits         
    visitsSeries = new XYSeries("Unique Visitors");           
    // Creating a dataset to hold each series       
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();      
    // Adding Visits Series to the dataset        
    dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);           
    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries     
    visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();       
    visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);         
    visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);         
    visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);       
    visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);       
    visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);      
    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart        
    multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();          
    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Visits Chart");        
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Seconds");      
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Count");         
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);  
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);         
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(100);          
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);         
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(10);       
    multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);          
    // Adding visitsRenderer to multipleRenderer  
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer 
    // should be same        
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);          
    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout     
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);         
    //mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);    
    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer);
    // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout       
    chartContainer.addView(mChart);   
}       

private class ChartTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{           
    // Generates dummy data in a non-ui thread        

    @Override        
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {           
        int i = 0;          
        try{             
            do{            
                String [] values = new String[2];           
                Random r = new Random();                
                int visits = r.nextInt(10);                
                values[0] = Integer.toString(i);              
                values[1] = Integer.toString(visits);             
                publishProgress(values);                    
                Thread.sleep(1000);                    
                i++;               
            }while(i<=100);          
        }catch(Exception e){ }         
        return null;             
    }              
    // Plotting generated data in the graph       

    @Override          
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {        
        visitsSeries.add(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]));     
        mChart.repaint();            
    }         
}          

@Override        
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {          
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);      
    return true;     
}
}
```